# JPype startJVM crashes due to insufficient memory

Tags: python, jpype

I'm working on simple Jpype example...

os : windows 10 64 bit
python : 3.8.10

D:\work\python>pip list
Package         Version
JayDeBeApi      1.2.3
JPype1          1.4.1
numpy           1.24.4
packaging       23.2
pandas          2.0.3
pip             23.3.1
python-dateutil 2.8.2
pytz            2023.3.post1
setuptools      56.0.0
six             1.16.0
tzdata          2023.3

source code :

```
try:
    print('BP0')
    jpype.startJVM()
    print('BP2')
    s = jpype.java.lang.String('Hello World!')
    return f'{s.toUpperCase()} (pid {os.getpid()})'
```

result :

BP0

There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 176 bytes for Arena::Amalloc
An error report file with more information is saved as:
D:\work\python\hs_err_pid1840.log

Process finished with exit code 1

There's no googling result about above.
Please help me.